# Is it possible to initialize an array to the type of a function's return value?

Tags: swift

For example, I've got an array declared outside of a loop that will populate itself inside of a loop, though I want to generalize this in case the API changes in the future.

```
var array: [TypeOfReturn]

for var i = 0; i < someArray.count; i++ {
    array = someFunction()
}

// --- elsewhere ---

func someFunction() -> [TypeOfReturn] {
    // Do work
}
```

What I'd love to do is take the type (in this case `[TypeOfReturn]`) and declare the array outside the loop to this type, and that's it.  I hate optionals and `AnyObject` isn't appropriate, and the syntax of the language doesn't seem to support this without some shenanigans.  Does anyone know what those shenanigans are?

Comment: Will the use of a `typealias` suffice for your needs?

Comment: It would, though I'd prefer something in-line to keep the coupling loose.  Something reflect-y.

Comment: If you really can't just define `TypeOfReturn` as a `struct` or `class` you might consider defining `TypeOfReturn` as a `protocol`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you say "these two things should be the same type", you are describing a generic. Unfortunately you will have to package up the things that use this type into a single generic, but it might be worth it to you. Example:

```
struct S<T> {
    var array : [T] = []
    func someFunction (x:T) -> [T] {
        return [x]
    }
}
var s = S<Int>()
s.array = s.someFunction(1)
```

Or it may be, depending on your needs, that only the array needs to be inside the generic struct:

```
struct S<T> {
    var array : [T]
}
func someFunction(x:Int) -> [Int] {
    return [x]
}
let s = S(array:someFunction(1))
```

The advantage of the second approach is only that the type T can be resolved implicitly.